# jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).iCheck is not a function TypeError: $(...).iCheck is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I use datepicker-babakhani(Javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting persian dates System.http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/beta/persian-date/) to select the solar date, but I get the following error, can I fix this error?
[image]

This is my code, which is in the file with the ‍`.bladeh.php` format

```
<input class="observer-example" />
<script>
    $('.observer-example').persianDatepicker({
        observer: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        altField: '.observer-example-alt'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The error is "jQuery is not defined". Did you load jQuery before loading the date library which depends on jQuery?

Comment: That 404 error seems like it's probably important too...

Comment: how to load jQuery??????Which file and in which path should be loaded???????